# Variogram of categorial data?

Tags: categorical-data, autocorrelation, spatial, variogram

I have a thematic map as raster data with classes assigned as numbers: 1,2,3,4. These are categorial classes and have no linear meaning. I am interested if there is spatial autocorrelation in this landscape. I can generate a variogram of this land cover using gstat. Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(elsa)
require(gstat)

file <- system.file('external/lc_example.grd',package='elsa') 
lc <- raster(file)
plot(lc,main='Land cover: a categorical map')
lc
temp <- as(lc, 'SpatialPointsDataFrame')
temp <- temp[sample(1:length(temp),1000),]   # subsample to reduce processing time
temp@data$lc
```

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAFVG.png) 5 3 3 6 3 5 3 5 5 3 3 2 ....

```
variolc <- variogram(temp@data$lc ~ 1, data = temp,width = 100)
plot(variolc)
```

[image]

However, is it statistically meaningful to calculate a variogram of this land cover map?

Comment: No: this variogram is (almost) meaningless. (If you're unconvinced, replace your numerical codes 1,2,3,4 with a completely different set of numbers, such as a permutation, and recompute the variogram and observe what happens. This recoding of a categorical variable is always permissible: indeed, this possibility is what *defines* a categorical variable.)  Other tools are needed to study spatial correlations among such categorical data.  Variograms can have a role: for instance, you can code your categories as a triple of indicator variables and explore their variograms and cross-variograms.

Comment: Thanks. That was my suspicion. I thought there might be a setting or a trick that could take this into account. If you add it as an answer, I will validate it. Also, I am curious to hear about any way to assess spatial autocorrelation (in particular range) from land cover data).